About solana token Decimals
I'm new to Solana. I've created a swapping method to swap Solana tokens, and it has successfully swapped tokens. However, I'm stuck on one problem: I need the decimals of the token to swap Solana tokens. Does anybody know how to get Solana token decimals using any library or something similar? I've used Jupiter API and Moralis API, but I didn't get the correct decimals. Or perhaps I've made some mistakes. So, if anybody knows how to get it, please message me.

use getParsedAccountInfo rpc method to fetch token details of a particular mint address
const result = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(new PublicKey(mint), {
          commitment: 'confirmed',
        })

then
const {decimals} = result?.value?.data?.parsed?.info || {};

